# how to pass ruby variable to jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

How can i do simple thing like this:

```
  $('#show_history').click(function(){
        var c_user = "#{current_user.id}";
        alert(c_user);
    });
```

Comment: Does [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870533/rails-3-and-jquery-how-to-add-ruby-code-into-an-element) answer your question?

Comment: Checkout this screencast > http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript

Comment: In your template .js.erb put something like `c_user = "<%= current_user.id%>";`

Comment: this works on page but not in js file

Answer (score 0):

For me `<%=j some_ruby_expression %>` worked